# PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class AdminImportControllerCore in

Tags: php, file, class, curl, redeclare

I have a script with cURL to initiate other script that import products and categories in prestashop.

This is the script which start with cURL:

```
define('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_', getcwd());
include_once(_PS_ADMIN_DIR_.'/../config/config.inc.php');
include_once(_PS_ADMIN_DIR_.'/../config/defines.inc.php');
include_once(_PS_ADMIN_DIR_.'/functions.php');
include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../controllers/admin/AdminImportController.php';

if (!isset($_GET['entity'])) die(); 

$import = New AdminImportController(); 
switch ($_GET['entity']) { 
case 0: 
    loadCategoriesPost(); 
    $import->categoryImport(); 
    break;

  case 1:
    loadProductsPost();
    $import->productImport();
    break;

}
```

My problem is that the seconds script generate an error from "include_once dirname(**FILE**).'/../controllers/admin/AdminImportController.php';":

PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class AdminImportControllerCore in...

I have tried to use include_once, **DIR**, also I looked for in that included files a line with "new AdminImportController();" but I don't found nothing.

Thanks!

Comment: One of the other include files may be including `AdminImportController.php` with a different pathname, maybe an absolute path instead of using `..`. Search for that in all the other include files.

Comment: @Barmar That shouldn't be an issue. PHP knows it's the same file, even if the includes use different type of paths to point to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look inside the `AdminImportController.php` file. My guess is that *it* is also including the file that defines the `AdminImportControllerCore` class, and that it is not using the `include_once` verity of the include functions.

That would mean that your main page is defining the class through the `include_once` call, and then when it includes the `AdminImportController` class, the include there kicks in and tries to re-define the core class, with the results you described.

I suggest you look into PHP's [autoloader feature](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php). It'll save you all the headaches associated with manually including files like that. It also tends to promote good file and class naming practices.